# Huawei AppGallery Failed to obtain the authentication code

Tags: android, release, huawei-mobile-services, uploading, appgallery-connect

I'm trying to upload the final apk in the AppGallery store but I get this message blocking me from uploading my app into the store. I tried many solutions I change my browser also check my connection but everything looks good  Please, anyone, know something I need help with, thanks

[image: this is the warning appear]

[image: try to upload but nothings showing up just keep loading]

Answer (score 1):

This warning is usually caused by the network issue.

It is recommended that you check your network to see if it is connected to a VPN or proxy.If the problem persists, could try to check your browser log and see the error.

Answer (score 1):

If you face the same problem just wait a couple of hours and it will be fixed by itself, I didn't do anything. be patient and wait